# iif function Access - wrong result

Tags: ms-access, iif

I am launching a query (Access 2003) from VB.NET app.

`select id, customer, date, total, iif ([amountGet] - [amountSent] = [total], 'Yes', 'No') as result from invoices`

but **iif** returns wrong results

**TABLE**
id: 1
customer: pepe
date: 01/01/2014
total: 1,8 
amountGet: 5 
amountSent: 3,2

**RESULT:**
Returns "No"

when should return "Yes" because 5-3,2=1,8

Comment: What types are amountGet, amountSent and total? This is most likely due to a rounding error.

Comment: Double (automatic decimals)

Comment: Could it be a problem with your region settings using `,` instead of `.` for the decimal position?  Have you tried running this in the immediate window?

Comment: Hello: following the comments of jpw, now I put round numbers to 2 decimals and seems works well.  iif ( round([amountGet] - [amountSent],2) = round([total],2) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rounding numbers to same number of decimals, in my case 2 decimals, returns correct result:

```
iif ( round([amountGet] - [amountSent],2) = round([total],2) )
```

@jpw thanks for the comment, because it has helped me to find the solution